# how to install intellij IDEA community edition on Windows 7 32-bit?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, installation, ide

when i am trying to install intelliJ IDEA on windows 7 32 bit ..the option
 **32 bit launcher**

and the option **Download and install JRE x86 by Jetbrains** are

disabled.. how to overcome this problem? any help will be appreciated..

thanks...

i have included the screenshot for the same..

[image: intellij IDEA Installation]

Comment: It's disabled, but checked. Just continue.

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj  sorry..i got you.. do in need to check path veriable and create association too.. or just continue...?

Comment: You don't have to check anything. I don't know what your plans are, but you don't need any of that to get a 100 % capable IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is by design. The 32-bit launcher and x86 JRE options are forcibly enabled since you are installing on a 32-bit Windows version. IDE will download x86 JetBrains Runtime during the installation as it's not bundled and is required to run on the 32-bit systems.